# postgres: reset pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have a pg10 replica that got promoted to master and have monitoring around the following query to monitor replication

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())) as lag
```

That works great but it got promoted and that state seems like it's still there so it seems that host which is the main now has a 40000s replication delay.

So looking for a way to remove that stat so it's not there or reports as 0s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pg_is_in_recovery () function to determine if this postgresql instance is primary or in hot standby mode.

It is possible to change the monitoring query to something like

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())) as lag
WHERE pg_is_in_recovery()
```

(missing `FROM` clause is not error, it is not necessary)

or

```
SELECT case when not pg_is_in_recovery() then 0 else
   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()))
   end as lag
```

or something around.

Comment: worked great.. thanks!